# BeagleBone Black использует только 4gb от cd карты в 16gb

Tags: debian, embedded

У меня BeagleBone Black rev C. Установил через balenaEtcher по инструкции с официального сайта дистрибутив AM3358 Debian 10.3 2020-04-06 4GB SD IoT. На самом деле не только его, пробовал много других, везде одинаково. Выделяется только 3.5gb, остальная память cd карты не используется и я не могу ничего установить через apt-get. Пишет ошибку u dont have enough free space in .../arhives. Еще через MiniTool Partition Wizard пробовал увеличить размер раздела, не хочет увеличивать.

Comment: У вас прямо в названии стоит 4G. Вы хотите потом расширить размер? Не уверен, что у вас там GPT таблица, а так `parted` в руки и вперёд! Ещё вариант `gdisk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается это распространенная проблема и решается она через удаление раздела и создание нового более большого через fdisk.

https://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/expanding-your-beaglebone-microsd-filesystem/